# How to get user input in Twillio on the same file

Tags: php

i want to get user input in the same file and use for some manipulation.

```
    echo '<Say>Please enter the number followed by hash key..</Say>';

    echo '< Gather  '.$number1    = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'].'> </Gather>' ;

    echo '<Say>Enter the secod number followed by the hash key...</Say>';
    echo '< Gather  '.      $number2 = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'].'> </Gather>' ;
    $sum = $number1 + number2
    echo ' $sum';
```

is this a proper way to use the Gather ?

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean by "is this a proper way" ? Elaborate.

Comment: I want to Gather users input and assign them to variables so i can use the variables for some calculations. I want to know how to get these inputs in the same file.

Comment: No no, what I meant is "edit and improve your question", as such it might be considered as "unsalvageable" and get closed. Add that text in question, add relevant tags (Twillio ? Gather ?), maybe a link or two, explain what is wrong at present with that code, ... All of this is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask